# How to set json response data in editext using android?

Tags: android-fragments, android-asynctask

How to set JSON response data in editext using android and how to seperate JSON values?

when i click the image button then goes to Aync task and gets the customer details ... and how to put the json in editext like name ,address,phonenumber etc

Comment: Add some text to the question body - not only code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to set complete response to edit text, you can achieve this by 
   editText.setText(response) in onPost execute of asyntask. If you want to parse 
you can use this code

```
JSONObject res = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject customerObject = res.getJSONObject("customer");
String mail = customerObject.getString("email");
```

where response is string response from server

Similarly you can get value from customer object and set edit text

Comment: thank u .. how to set the json response in edittext..?? i am passing Asyn task from fragment

Comment: you want to set complete json to edit text or a value from json string. are u using asyntask in seprate file

Comment: only values like name,phone number,email etc..yes Async in seprate file

Comment: if you are using asynctask in seprate file, you have to pass edit text in ansyntask, somthing like  new MyasyncTask(editText).execute(). and make constructor that takes edit text in Asyntask file . If you are using asyntask in same file just set value in onPost execute of asyntask and ping me if you face any problem